# How to show that a clause is derivable from a set of clauses in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, first-order-logic

Using the logic programming notation, given the following clause:

```
C = m(P,X) <- m(Q,X), m(R,X)
```

It is possible to resolve the head of C with the first body literal of C' to give the substitution `{P/Q',X/X'}` and the clause:

```
D = m(P',X') <- m(Q,X'), m(R,X'), m(R',X').
```

How can I show this with Prolog? In other words, how can I show that you can derive `D` from `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clarified your question after my first post, but there is already some discussion below it. To prevent confusion, I will not edit it but write a second one:

There are two reasons why you cannot directly write down your problem as a prolog program:

- you want to resolve without query
- you want to see the resolvent of a (single) derivation step

Therefore we will encode the clause database in the predicate mi_clause which has two arguments: the head and a list with the body. The predicate clause_clause_resolvent has 6 arguments: head and body for each clause as well as for the resolvent. Here, the resolvent is the result of resolving over the head of the second clause with the first element of the body of the first clause. Doing it the other way round would also work.

```
mi_clause(m(_P,X), [m(_Q,X), m(_R,X)]). % your original clause, anonymous variables are prefixed with _ for compiler reasons

clause_clause_resolvent( Head1, Body1, Head2, Body2, RHead, RBody) :- 
    copy_term(clause(Head1,Body1), clause(H1,B1)), % create a variant of the first clause
    copy_term(clause(Head2,Body2), clause(H2,B2)), % same for second clause
    B1 = [H2|Rest1],                               % the prolog execution order always uses the first literal
    H1 = RHead,                                    % head of resolvent is the same (is only resolved with the query)
    append(Rest1, B2, RBody).                      % create the new body
```

The comments should be more or less self-explanatory: The copy_terms create variants of the input clause, otherwise you could lose resolvents. Then you pick the first element of the second clauses' body and try to unifiy. Actually, this unification is sufficient to instantiate both clauses correctly. Now we create our resolvent clause:the head of clause 1 is carried over(modulo the unifier substitution), the resolvent's body is clause 1's body without the resolved literal prepended to the body of the second clause's body.

Now try out the predicate, for instance in SWI Prolog:

```
?- mi_clause(H1,B1), mi_clause(H2,B2), clause_clause_resolvent(H1,B1,H2,B2,RH,RB).
H1 = m(_G1028, _G1029),
B1 = [m(_G1034, _G1029), m(_G1040, _G1029)],
H2 = m(_G1043, _G1044),
B2 = [m(_G1049, _G1044), m(_G1055, _G1044)],
RH = m(_G1068, _G1069),
RB = [m(_G1080, _G1069), m(_G1099, _G1069), m(_G1105, _G1069)].
```

As you can see, H1 and H2 are variants of your clause head containing fresh anonoymous variables. Still all elements of RB are of the form m(_, _G1069), obtaining a variant of the clause you expected.

If you want to check a general resolution step, replace the line B1 = [H2|Rest1] with member_of_rest(H2, B1, Rest1) and define this as:

```
member_of_rest(X, [X|Xs], Xs).
member_of_rest(X, [H|Xs], [H|Ys]) :-
    member_of_rest(X, Xs, Ys).
```

As a nice exercise you could extend the program by the deductive closure of clause_clause_resolvent to see arbitrary resolution sequences(you might want to be sure of the chaining order or you run into infinite recursions).

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to general Resolution, Prolog has an order in which clauses get resolved. This means, in general you cannot force prolog to resolve two literals against each other. The main idea of the reasoning in Prolog is that in the case of Horn clauses (only one positive literal, 0+ negative literals), after each resolution step you end up with a new Horn clause. You can only complete a proof of the empty clause by resolving with a purely negative clause. In Prolog, this clause is supplied by the user in the form of a query. This query guides the proof strategy of Prolog.

Perhaps let's look at the classical Aristoteles is a human example:

We know Aristoteles is a philosopher (1) and that all philosophers are human(2). Therefore Aristoteles is human.

```
philosopher(aristoteles).   % (1)
human(X) :- philosopher(X). % (2)
```

Now we formulate our query:

```
?- human(aristoteles). % (3)
```

Prolog looks for a clause with a head (the positive clause) unifiable with (3) from top to bottom. The head of clause (1) does not unify, so we try clause (2) and find a (most general) unifier: X = aristoteles. We now derive the clause:

```
:- philosopher(aristoteles). % (4)
```

which we can resolve with clause (1), again with the unifier X = aristoteles. Reaching the empty clause - Hooray we have a proof!

What is essential in this derivation is the query. In your case we can actually formulate a query which will do what you wanted. C1 and C2 is the same clause (modulo renaming of variables), so we write down:

```
m(P,X) :- m(Q,X), m(R,X). % (5)
```

if we now query for m(A,Y), we start a derivation process which mimics the step you wanted. Resolving the query with (5), can substitute P = A, X = Y and obtain:

```
:- m(Q,A), m(R,A). % (6)
```

We start by trying to resolve over m(Q,A), which again matches rule (5) with P = Q, A = X:

```
:- m(Q,A), m(R,A). % (7)
```

Since clauses (6) and (7) are the same, it is clear that no number of resolution steps will reach the empty clause. In other words, Prolog will be stuck in an endless loop(depending on optimizations, it might not even fill up th execution stack and silently loop, otherwise you get an out of stack error).

To make your query terminate, you could add the fact

```
m(a,b). % (8)
```

above inference rule (5) to your rule database. Since Prolog processes clauses from top to bottom and literals from left to right, placing it below will put the clause to a position where it will never be resolved (it is hidden by the infinite derivation sequence of resolutions with clause (5)).

I hope, this helps a bit with understanding what's going on. If not, I can always add more ;)

P.S. I made a small didactic jump - the query is the negation of the purely negative clause you need to supply to a theorem prover. Since the query is user defined, you just think of Prolog deriving it instead of resolving with its negation. This also gets you around the necessity to introduce skolem symbols.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not address the question, which is how to show that you can resolve `C3` from self-resolving `C1`.

Comment: Prolog does not do single resolution steps, you can not start without a query. Self resolution is contained in the derivation i showed above, but the first step is with the query, so a literal is missing:

Comment: (Q): :- m(Q,Y). and (5): m(P,X) :- m(Q,X), m(R,X). will be resolved to a new goal (6) :- m(Q,A), m(R,A). Now prolog will try self resolution with (5), obtaining again (6) - which is a subclause of the clause C3 you provided. Feeding this to a prolog interpreter will give you an endless loop which generates clause (6) over and over, so you will not get any output at all. Moreover, the interpreter will only return an answer substitution for your query, not the resolution proof it obtained. (You can write a so-called metacircular-interpreter to trace the steps, but usually you don't get them)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but you can trace a query to see the resolutions during a proof search.

Comment: This is true, although it is a debug feature of specific Prolog interpreters. What i wanted to point out is that the Prolog language does not return proof objects as a result (= an object which can be further processed by prolog) out of the box, but there are multiple ways to obtain it.